# Facebook connect API : Get user email

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a website in php where i have integrated a Facebook Connect API which enabled the Facebook login button.

My code to get user details looks like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // added in v4.0.0
    require_once 'autoload.php';
    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\GraphUser;
    use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

    // init app with app id and secret
    $appID = 'app id';
    $appSecret = 'app secret code';
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $appID, $appSecret);

    // login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/test/facebook_new/fbconfig.php' );

    try {
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
        // When Facebook returns an error
    } catch( Exception $ex ) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
    }

    // see if we have a session
    if ( isset( $session ) ) {

        // graph api request for user data
        $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
        $response = $request->execute();

        // get response
        $profile = $response->getGraphObject('Facebook\GraphUser');

        var_dump($profile);

    } else {
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
        header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
    }
?>
```

After eecuting this code, `var_dump($profile)` displays only the `User Facebook ID` and his `Full Name` as displayed on the picture below:

[image: Image showing the result]

What I want to get is the email. The email can be accessed through `'Facebook\GraphUser'` but I really dont know what is wrong with my code.

Kindly help me solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me?fields=name,email');`

It is called "Declarative Fields", you have to specify the fields you want to get returned since v2.4 of the Graph API.

Also, make sure the user is authorized with the `email` permission.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook users in their settings can set their email as private or public. This might be the reason it is not showing up for you.